# How to programmatically use UIButton in iPhone Development

Tags: iphone

I encountered a weird problem.  when I try to add a UIButton in my customized ui view. the button title cannot display.  only draw the outside roundrect. regardless invoke setTitle:forState:   or button.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];  it also doesn't work.  but for backgroundColor,  at the rectangle angle corner, the bgcolor seems take a little bit filling up.

I initialized this button in "initWithNibName" method of custom view controller.  is it ok?  even I set this button reference to view controller's view property or just added it into other view. this issue also happens.

Answer (score 2):

You should set your button values in -viewDidLoad. If you try to do this in -initWithNibNamed:bundle:, the outlets won't be set up yet, and your button value will be nil.

Comment: Thank you Ben,  I see, I will try this way later.  But I still confused, when I run the simulator, The console doesn't print any crash log. application runs looks fine. I don't know why.

Comment: Mikael, what you're doing won't actually cause an error: sending messages (like `-setBackgroundColor:`, which is what changing the `backgroundColor` property does) to a nil object just doesn't do anything. In Objective-C parlance, you're “messaging nil”, which the runtime can handle just fine.